# Java Spring Boot, Could not determine recommended JdbcType for <class>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have seen different responses to similar cases but none seem to work for me.

In my Spring boot application, there are many entities connected to databases, but I get an error in one of them and it just doesn't make sense to me.

The error is as followed (full error down below) :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'valorantEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/example/tournaments/config/ValorantConfig.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.example.tournaments.model.general.TeamEntity`

The error is refering to the class TeamEntity. This class is a very simple entity class with a auto generated field "id", a field "name" and a field "players" that is not being saved to the database. The class looks like this:\

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teams")
public class TeamEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @Transient
  private List<PlayerEntity> players = new ArrayList<PlayerEntity>();

  public TeamEntity() {
  }

  public TeamEntity(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public TeamEntity(String name, List<PlayerEntity> players) {
    this.name = name;
    this.players = players;
  }

  public void addPlayer(PlayerEntity player) {
    players.add(player);
  }

  // getters and setters

}
```

I doubt that it has to do something with it but the TeamEntity class is also linked in one other table:

```
@Id
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_id")
  private TournamentEntity tournament;

  @Id
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
  private PlayerEntity player;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
  private TeamEntity team;
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'valorantEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/example/tournaments/config/ValorantConfig.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.example.tournaments.model.general.TeamEntity`
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.example.tournaments.TournamentsApplication.main(TournamentsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.example.tournaments.model.general.TeamEntity`
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1766) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

If it helps, this is the "teams" table:
[image]

I already tried to remove the players and just have the fields "id" and "name", but I get the same error so it would very much suprise me if "players" was the problem.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace as code formatted text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: The @Id annotations on 
  private TournamentEntity tournament;
and
  private PlayerEntity player;
are obviously wrong! What would you like to do with that!?

Comment: @MirandaVeracruzDeLaHoyaCardina it is a Composite Primary Key and that part works as expected

Comment: @Ajiva Did you solve your issue? Could you please provide the solution - or upvote the correct answer!

Comment: @max So if I remember correctly, my TeamEntity was in the folder model.general. But this conflicts when you have two Entity managers using that class. Instead of one general table entity, i made two (almost) identical and put one of them in the "Apex" folder and one of them in the "Valorant" folder, together with the other models.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Hibernate doesn't know that `TeamEntity` is an entity. Is that class properly scanned by Springs `@EntityScan`? Or did you make sure this class is listed in the persistence.xml?

I think there is an open issue in the Hibernate issue tracker that is about improving the error message for this case, but I can't find it right now. If anyone digs it up, please add a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A @OneToOne relationship is bidirectional and has to be defined in both classes.

Look at @ManyToOne and @OneToMany. If the unnamed class is, for example, called `MatchEntity`, then a Team has many matches (@OneToMany) and the Player in the match is a member of a team (@ManyToOne).

Comment: "A @OneToOne relationship is bidirectional "

This is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

By far, the most common cause of the BeanCreationException is Spring trying to inject a bean that doesn't exist in the context. Please refer [Spring BeanCreationException](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beancreationexception)

The @Entity for which Spring Boot can't find JDBC type.. I added @OneToMany relationship as it was applicable in my case and the exception got resolved.